# JQuery .click pass variables

Tags: jquery, variables, click

propb. very simple, but not for me.
Looking to pass a variable on a click function to show either div a or div b based on the a link clicked.  My code is something like this

```
$('.view').click(function() {
    var id = this.id.replace('view_', "");
if(id=1) { $('#show').show('slow'); }
if(id=2 ) { $('#show2').show('slow'); }
$('#categories').hide('slow');
    return false;
  });
  });
```

But OBVIOUSLY the if statements are wrong - I know that I am just using them as an example.  Any suggerstions?
Thanks in adavance

Comment: It looks like you found @naeem's answer helpful. Don't forget to mark it as accepted if that is the case. I see you are new here, so I wanted to make sure you knew how important it is to accept answers on *every* question you ask if possible. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this...

```
var id = parseInt(this.id.replace('view_', ""), 10);
if(id === 1) { 
 $('#show').show('slow'); 
} else if(id === 2 ) { 
 $('#show2').show('slow'); 
}
```

1 '=' is used for assignment
2 '==' is comparison with type conversion
3 '===' is comparison *without* type conversion

Comment: Perfect Naeem, thanks, works stright out of box.  I am just learning JQuery/java so some of the lang is a bit strange for me as a PHP guy
Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

You are assigning the value of `1` to `id` instead of testing for a match:

```
if(id = 1) {} // WRONG: this means if id is successfully SET to 1
```

Here is what it should look like:

```
$('.view').click(function() {
    var id = this.id.replace('view_', "");

    if(id == 1)       { $('#show').show('slow'); }
    else if(id == 2 ) { $('#show2').show('slow'); }

    $('#categories').hide('slow');

    return false;
});
```

If you find yourself making this mistake a lot, you should switch the test around:

```
if( 1 == id) {} // Works
if( 1 = id ) {} // Throws JS error instead of failing silently
```

Comment: +1 this post finally reveals why people write (1==id) instead of the other way round

Comment: Well explained, +1 for that

Answer (score 0):

If your link id's are `view_1` and `view_2`, then all should be fine here, except for the fact that you're using `=` rather than comparison `==`.

If your `show` elements were called `show1` and `show2`, rather than `show` and `show2`, you could of course do:

```
$('.view').click(function() {
    $('#show' + this.id.replace('view_','')).show('slow');
    $('#categories').hide('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Doug pointed out, the problem is in conditional assignment

You should also consider renaming your ids to directly match your view ids, so you can do it without test cases, only by string concatenation:'

```
$('.view').click(function() {
    var id = this.id.replace('view_', "");

    $('#show' + id).show('slow'); // doesn't have to use if statements

    $('#categories').hide('slow');

    return false;
});
```